# Airflow - Define the duration a DAG can run for

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am just trying to figure if there is a way to limit the duration of a DAG in airflow. For example, set max time a DAG can run for to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

DAGs have `dagrun_timeout` parameter indeed, but it works only when `max_active_runs` for the DAG is reached (16 by default). For example if you have 15 active DAGs, the scheduler will just launch 16th. But before launching next one the scheduler will wait until one of previous finishes *or* exceedes timeout.

But you can use `execution_timeout` for task instance. This parameter works unconditionally.